# NotifyDataSetChanged on different fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm using a Master / Detail flow (not the default one), so I have one `fragment` that contains the stuff of the `RecyclerView` and when I click on a item I see on other `fragment` the detail of that item, it works, but now I want to delete this item from the detail fragment, and when I click on delete it refreshes and then notifydatasetchanged.

What's the problem? I have the Adapter on my ListFragment and on my DetailFragment I only can delete the item from my SQLite nothing else, I'd like to refresh the list.

Activity -- Where I create the listFragment

Fragment1 -- ListFragment (RecyclerView, Adapter, Sqlite(For fetch products))

Fragment2 -- DetailFragment (Sqlite(to delete item))

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        Fragment list = new ListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.list,list).commit();
    }
}
```

On my `ListFragment` I have those attributes

```
private SQLiteAdapter sqliteAdapter;
private Context mContext;
private Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Product> data;
```

Then I put the data with a method that open the sqliteAdapter and then fetch all products and then closses the connection.

On my DetailFragment I have the SQLite object to get the product sent from the adapter (id product) and then show info about this product.
Now I can delete an object, but it's not refreshing from ListFragment, I'm wondering where to put this SQLite object on Activity or in both fragments is ok

Comment: Please show an [mcve] that illustrates your problem. In particular, show the activity, the fragments, and the adapter.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What do I have to put???? a button with a method to delete???? I'm just explaining my scenario, look my edit though

Comment: Please read the link I gave previously. It is difficult to tell how to fix your problem without some actual code.

Comment: I do not need code, I need reasoning information, I mean, if you read my question (my skeleton) you know what I've, if you don't understand something let me know and I'll clarify you, but from now, I don't know why you want to see my ListFragment / Detail Fragment if in my question I've put what contains each one.

Comment: I am more than willing to help you. But to do so, I need to see your code. Telling me that I don't need to is like telling your doctor that she should be able to diagnosis what is wrong just by telling her that you have a cough.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Is a good point to put the instance on the Activity and all of the adapter on it and then call those methods on Fragment?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Check edit

Comment: Thanks for showing some code. We still need more details to help you. The example is not complete. You should fix the compiler errors by putting all methods inside a class, just like you have in your actual code. You should show your activity class and both fragment classes. Note this does **not** mean show all of the code from all of these classes. Just show the code which is important to this question.

Comment: ok, I'll update the quesiton

Comment: But my question is how to get reference from DetailFragment of my Adapter to make the notifyDataSetChanged() and if it's a good point to put the object of Sqlite in Activity to avoid make the same instance of sqlite on both fragments (if it's possible)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You got my question?

Comment: Are both fragments visible in the same parent activity at the same time? If so, I suggest that you google "communicate between two fragments" or something similar.

Comment: Yes, they have the same parent Activity

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are only deleting the item from your database. You also need to delete it from the adapter's list or other data structure.

Comment: But there's no way to do that? Yes I'm deleting it from my database

Comment: @StuartDTO `You also need to delete it from the adapter's list or other data structure`, which means that the `List` or `Array` or any other data structure (where you put your data that you loaded from your database) sent to the Adapter, also needs to have an up-to-date content, in your case a removal of the record in question.